# Multivariable calculus - Continuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The following function is not defined for $x=0$ and $y=0:$
$$f(x,y) = \frac {xy} {x^2+y^2}$$
Is it possible to add there a function value in such way that the modified function is continuous at zero point?

I tried to find the  limit 
$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$.

If $\ y=0,$ then $f(x, 0) = \frac 0{x^2} = 0$,
if $\ x=0,$ then $f(0, y) = \frac 0{y^2} = 0$.

But for example:
If $\ y=x,$ then for all $x \neq 0$ is $f(x, x) = \frac{x^2} {x^2+x^2} = \frac 12$

Since I have obtained different limits along different paths, the given limit does not exist and the function is discontinuous.

I am not sure if I am right, but I think that is not possible to add a function value in such way that the modified function is continuous at zero point.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your posts will be more legible if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.

Comment: Use $$x=r\cos(\phi),y=r\sin(\phi)$$

Comment: You have to study whether the function has a finite or infinite discontinuity at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I would say you did it correctly since if it was possible, the value you should insert is equal to the limit across any path. Hence, via your calculation, it follows that the to be inserted value should be equal to two different values which is not possible

Comment: @carlgar Your computation and conclusion are correct.